# Which shell is this?

Tags: shell, autocomplete

Which shell is this?

[image]

How to get that auto-complete?

Comment: I remember seeing a "what prompt / shell / package is this?" question or two on the main site, so I think it'd be OK there. Notice that the terminal's title bar briefly says "fish", which is a shell.

Comment: That looks like some mac terminal, probably, but there's no way of knowing. The terminal decorations will depend on your GUI theme. Are you really asking what _terminal_ this is or are you wondering about the shell? Either way, please ask on the main site, yes. This is certainly off topic here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, you were right. It is terminal called "Fish" :) I initially thought it was project name or something.

Comment: I get the same behavior in `zsh` using `zsh-autosuggestions`.

Comment: This is not a shell! Yes, it is, and it is cool, but it is more a git frontend and a text editor with very good interaction WITH the shell. This is not a critique. It just belongs in a slightly different category than "shell". Needs a movie to show the features -- that too shows how special it behaves, and, well, must _feel_ when you use it.

Comment: OK I read in wikipedia. This is interesting. Almost like a perl shell, so friendly does it break with SOME of bash syntax. Is there any technical connection with bash? I think bash itself carries it's parent's name (Bourne) . I am impressed. But: this is not a POSIX shell ;)

Comment: Too fast and too many things happening, for me. Have you tried asking it?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor you mean me? "asking it?" I have treid to _read_  it! I said "this is a git frontend" before I put on my reading glasses...which I did after I wikied "fish". It is a shell **for a GUI**, a secondary shell, and I like the concept a lot. But for any classic system (startup) you need a "normal" shell. Halfways POSIX compliant. And bash **et al.** can do 80% of these things too -- in the end more portably i.e. better maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell being used in the shown terminal is the `fish` shell.  The `fish` shell is a non-POSIX shell (and hence provides a different syntax from shells like `bash` and `zsh`) that gives the user what it calls "autosuggestions" based on previously entered commands, which is what is being displayed in the GIF animation in the question.

I recognized it as the `fish` shell since I recognize the autosuggestion feature and also the bold `I` in the prompt denoting "insert mode" (in the command line editing mode based on the Vi editor) and also the particular type of menus used in auto-completions.  Oh, and the window title of the terminal says `(fish)` when the shell itself is the foreground job (which makes it not just a guess that it's `fish`).

Additional information and installation instructions for the `fish` shell can be found at its [webpage](https://fishshell.com/).

Comment: I just wanted to mention one thing here for future users. The style/status of every line is achieved by [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) plugin. I was struggling to understand how it was achieved :)